# Extract only 64 Characters

Tags: notepad++

> ('AJacquey|f640cad00a11f9595712efb13fa11ada12409dba67ec57c9482f9389e88d91cf

i need only

> f640cad00a11f9595712efb13fa11ada12409dba67ec57c9482f9389e88d91cf

need an auto regex way

Comment: `/|(.){64}/` ... ? And note that this is for questions, not a place to dump requirements and expect others to do your job for you.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*\|([a-z0-9]{64}).*$`
- Replace with: `$1`